# SQL injection setString

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-injection

Is there a possible way to inject some code in the the following statements (I tried the sleep function and it worked , but i'm looking for a way to get the table's name):

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
      "select password from " + USERS_TABLE_NAME + " where userid = ? and password = ?");
statement.setString(1, username_login);
statement.setString(2, password_login);
```

Comment: Related, maybe even a dupe: [How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1582161)

Comment: The above query implies that you are storing your passwords as clear text, which by itself is not a good thing.  That aside, you can't really inject a prepared statement; this is the whole point of using a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using a prepared statement makes the code safe from SQL injection; the only way to inject some code into that query would be to tamper with `USERS_TABLE_NAME` somehow. I can't tell much about this as you didn't provide any code related to this, but if it's just a string constant you should be fine.

Comment: But can it still be injectable ? I read it can be be injectable using the ORDER BY clause !!

Answer (score 0):

> I read it can be be injectable using the ORDER BY clause !!

The example you showed above is not vulnerable to injection in the ORDER BY clause. The query doesn't even have an ORDER BY clause, or any string concatenation that could append an ORDER BY clause to the end of the query.

SQL injection can occur only if you allow untrusted content to modify the SQL query before passing it to the `prepare()` method.